# How can I define an email template in Outlook with a pre-set subject and stubbed body - without sending it?

Tags: templates, automation, outlook

I have to send a daily update email and would like to know how I can have the email stubbed out automatically. I would probably add this to my start up, so each morning when I turn my computer on as well as launching Outlook and my browsers the email would be sitting ready for me to simply detail my morning and afternoon work. Only at the end of the day would I manually fill out the addresses to send it to.

*Edit - 08/07/11 16:43*
It sounds, in hind-sight, like a template is what I want, one where the date is programmatically set in the subject and that I would like the templated email to be opened automatically 1st thing in the morning

The emails all take the same format; the subject line is "Daily update dd/mm/yy"
Then in the body:

Morning

- List item

Afternoon

- List item

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source of a small script sending an email in PowerShell :

```
Param([string[]] $to = $(throw "Please specifie a destination address"),
      [string] $subject = "<No Subject>",
      [string] $body = $(throw "Please specify message content"),
      [string] $smtpHost = $(throw "please specify an SMTP server address"),
      [string] $from = "$($env:UserName)@silogix-fr.com"
)

## Create the message
$email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

## Fill the fields
foreach($mailTo in $to)
{
  $email.To.Add($mailTo)
}

$email.From = $from
$email.Subject = $subject
$email.Body = $body

## Send the message
$client = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtpHost
$client.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$client.Send($email)
```

Comment: I removed the $to array, $smtpHost, hardcoded my email address, removed the foreach loop and didn't include the block to send the email. So I _did change it a bit_, but when I run the script nothing happens. I'm assuming the email would be created in memory but because I'm not doing anything with it that it gets destroyed when the script exits.

What I want to happen is for the email to be created and left open for me to work on during the day. I'm thinking along the lines of a template I guess

Comment: How you do this wiht templates, is you create the message you want to use as a template inside a html file, use get-content on the html and then run whatever changes you want to make to it through a separate piece of powershell code and make $body the html.

Comment: Sorry, I d'on understand your question, this template just send a mail.

Comment: The aim is not to send the email. I want to open an email with the subject and body partially filled out, then add to the email over the whole day. I would open it around 9am, and write in the email every hour. Only at the end of the day do I want to send the email, so that has to be a manual process.